# XSLT - how to test value

Tags: xpath, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <QueryResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/QueryAuthRequests/Service1">
     <RespMessage xmlns="http://altsq/XMLSchema/epayments/standard">
        <PaymentList>
           <OriginatorsReference>0000000784</OriginatorsReference>
           <RecReference>0000000784</RecReference>
           <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
           <RequestDate>2022-11-16T11:40:39</RequestDate>
           <RequestMessage>Masked</RequestMessage>
           <ResponseMessage>No details available</ResponseMessage>
           <RequestStatus>A</RequestStatus>
        </PaymentList>
       </RespMessage>
  </QueryResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to test the value of request status but it doesn't seem to like the syntax. Whats the correct syntax to test the value

```
<form:field>
    <form:name>request_status</form:name>
    <xsl:when test="//.[local-name()='RequestStatus']/text() = 'A'">
            <form:value>Accepted</form:value>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <form:value>Refused</form:value>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</form:field>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:svc="http://tempuri.org/QueryAuthRequests/Service1"
xmlns:std="http://altsq/XMLSchema/epayments/standard"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap svc std">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="soap:Body/svc:QueryResponse/std:RespMessage/std:PaymentList/std:RequestStatus='A'">Accepted</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Refused</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>Accepted</output>
```

Comment: looks like i was missing the `<xsl:choose>` from my original code.